# Перенос вордпресс сайта на другой хост

Tags: php

При переносе сайта на Вордпресс на другой хост были проделаны следующие шаги:

1. сделаны копии базы и файлов.
2. на новом хосте создана база и туда выгружена база (она есть когда зайти под юзером в МайАдмин)
3. выгружены файлы со старого хоста на новый.
4. в файле ВП-КОНФИГ изменены 3 поля подключения к базе данных

Еще момент. В базу на старом хосте у меня пока доступа нет. И БЭКАП делал не я. Но момент такой что структура таблиц не совпадает с той которую я нашел в нете. Тоесть нет таблицы OPTION и других которые должны быть. Но контент таблиц совпадает с сайтом. Как такое может быть. Вопрос еще очень актуальный

Вопрос в том, что после того как перейти на сайт в новом хосте - начинается установка вордпресс.

Comment: Ну шаги правильные, а в чем заключается вопрос ?

Comment: Вот блин...сорри. вопрос в том, что после того как перейти на сайт в новом хосте - начинается установка вордпресс

Comment: А файлы именно перенесены, не было попыток развернуть дистрибутив вордпресса на новом сервере в эту папку ? Если нет - то думаю вордпресс не видит конфига, например на конфиге что то не так с правами доступа и он не читается

Comment: нет перенесли архивом и распакованы.

Comment: А файл .htaccess не забыли, а то он скрытый, может не попал в архив

Comment: нет. АКСЕС есть он не менялся.

Comment: в файле ВП-КОНФИГ там где строки дефайн - то пишет вторым параметром кучу непонятных символов

Comment: define('AUTH_KEY',         'впишите сюда уникальную фразу');

Comment: Там где "впишите сюда уникальную фразу'" - разная фигня из символов

Comment: Ну эти то ключи нормальные. как я их понимаю он их использует при шифровании паролей и т.п. они не должны меняться при переносе

Comment: ну ок...абра-кадабра - то так...но что может быть с этой фигней...я с вордпрессом не работал поэтому сложно что-то сказать.

Comment: из изменений было только в ВП-конфиг поменяны подключения к БД

Comment: Если доступ консолью на сервер есть, проверьте права доступа, особенно владельцев файлов. На старом сервере wp-config.php наверняка писался скриптом инсталляции и тогда на нем владельцем апач той системы и его ID может не совпадать с апачем на новой системе. А если переносили `tar` то он права мог криво развернуть. хотя чтение то должно быть ... см. ниже, там вам ответили про настройки базы ...

Comment: @Mike, отсутствующий htaccess может привести только к тому, что ссылки на сайте будут битыми, но главная страница должна работать. А судя по тому, что начинается установка - htaccess работает нормально. Права на чтение вроде по дефолту ставятся, поэтому даже если владелец не тот же, что и на старом сервере, то проблем быть не должно. Здесь даже на запись права не нужны, wp и без этого прекрасно работает

Comment: Кстати, а имя сайта не менялось ? Я сейчас смотрю код которым вордпресс проверяет установлен ли он ... И первым делом он сверяет имя сайта полученное из базы с url по которому к нему пришли. Но там еще куча проверок, пока разбираюсь ... Да, еще он какие то значения из кеша получает. что такое его кеш я не разбирался, но думаю какая то папка где то в глубине

Comment: да нет. тоже самое имя не менялось

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, WordPress просто "не видит" содержимого БД. БД пустая или неправильно выставлены права.

Проверьте перенесено ли на новый хост содержимое БД и права пользователя, который подключается к БД.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31545/discussion-on-answer-by-streletz------).