# Как загрузить сайт сделанный на Wordpress к себе на сайт-портфолио?

Tags: wordpress, cms

Сделала сайт на wordpress и скачала все файлы, положила его в свое портфолио, указала путь к нему, загрузила на сервер, при клике на него на сайте выдает такую ошибку:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in
>   /home/u481836830/public_html/ex_5/wp-content/themes/mh-newsdesk-lite/index.php
>   on line 1

Как правильно загрузить сайт, сделанный на Wordpress, к себе на сайт-портфолио?

Comment: Сайт на ворпресс -- это динамический сайт: помимо "скачать все файлы" вам понадобится сделать копию базы (и, возможно, поменять настройки подключения к базе). Кроме того, похоже, что вы скопировали не все файлы -- не хватает каких-то служебных файлов ядра вордпрес. Возможно, вам стоит рассмотреть альтернативу: в портфолио выложить статическую копию сайта (программы типа teleport pro) Перенос сайта по шагам вкратце был описан тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466125/

Comment: Кроме того, с весьма высокой степенью вероятности сайт на вордпресс находился в корне сайта, а выложить вы хотите в отдельную подпапку ex_5 -- поэтому нужно определиться с тем, как будут расположены каталоги движка, чтобы подключение происходило правильно.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал переносить сайт с помощью специальных плагинов. Например, XCloner. Может есть альтернативы более удобные и кт-то еще подскажет.

Answer (score 1):

Установите вордпресс с нуля в необходимом вам каталоге (в одной из папок вашего портфолио), настройте его, а потом переносите только созданную ранее тему и, в случае необходимости, записи из БД (если не знаете, как, то лучше плагином, например, [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)).